# Problems dropping an index in postgres using liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I'm hitting an issue in liquibase where I can't drop an index in my postgres db. The error reported by liquibase is

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: ERROR: index "value_idx" does not exist [Failed SQL: DROP INDEX VALUE_IDX]
```

I have connected to the database using psql and verified that the index does indeed exist (if the changeset is run without the drop index stanza)

```
\d data
          Table "someschema.data"
 Column |         Type          | Modifiers
--------+-----------------------+-----------
 value  | character varying(36) | not null
Indexes:
    "value_idx" UNIQUE, btree (value)
```

When running Liquibase updateSQL the `DROP INDEX` statement it generates is:

```
DROP INDEX VALUE_IDX;
```

My changelog is as follows:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <preConditions>
        <dbms type="postgresql"/>
    </preConditions>

    <changeSet author="beresfordt" id="1">

        <sql>
            CREATE SCHEMA SomeSchema;
        </sql>

        <createTable tableName="data" schemaName="someschema">
            <column name="value" type="varchar(36)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>

        <createIndex indexName="VALUE_IDX" schemaName="someschema"
                     tableName="data" unique="true">
            <column name="value" type="varchar(36)"/>
        </createIndex>

        <dropIndex catalogName="someschema"
                schemaName="someschema"
                tableName="data"
                indexName="VALUE_IDX"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I have also tried the following dropindex stanza:

```
        <dropIndex catalogName="someschema"
                schemaName="someschema"
                tableName="data"
                indexName="someschema.VALUE_IDX"/>
```

But I get a similar error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: ERROR: index "someschema.VALUE_IDX" does not exist [Failed SQL: DROP INDEX "someschema.VALUE_IDX"]
```

I am using Liquibase: 3.4.2 and Postgres: 9.5.1

Edit:

Tried on 3.3.0 and it works.

Bug raised in liquibase's jira: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2677

Comment: As the table is stored in the schema `someschema` the index needs to be qualified with the schema as well (unless `someschema` is in the `search_path` for the user). So it needs to be `drop index someschema.value_idx;` if I'm not mistaken - that seems like a bug in Liquibase

Comment: I tried explicitly putting the schema in the indexName attribute of the dropIndex stanza, but it didn't like that either. Will update the question

Comment: You already specified the schema in the `schemaName` attribute. If you put the schema name into the index name, Liquibase assumes the index is named `"someschema.VALUE_IDX"` which is something different then `"someschema"."value_idx"`. As I said: I do think this is a Liquibase bug. Short of use a custom `<sql>` tag, I don't think there is much you can do (and of course report the bug)

Comment: Yeah, I thought I'd try it just in case..

Comment: So this bug appears to have been introduced in 3.4.1; have raised https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2677

Comment: Good thinking! Thanks for all your help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a bug which exists in, at time of writing 3.4.1 and 3.4.2 of Liquibase.

This has been raised on Liquibase jira: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2677

edit:

This seems to have been resolved in the current head: '03b020ab895eb02c0e0aba90461cb7c628fa033f'

edit 2:

Update from Liquibase:

> The fix should be out with 3.5